# disable input fields on radio button change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have four radio buttons (fixed,percentage,monthly,yearly), I created A div with five fields, start price, end price, start date, end date and amount. What I want is when clicked on fixed or percentage button all five fields should be enabled and when clicked on monthly or yearly button start price and end price fields should be disabled (as I don't want to pass the values of these fields). I also have a add more mutton need to do the same for it i.e when add more rows to fixed/percentage all fields should be enabled and while adding rows to monthly/yerly fields, start/end price fields should be disabled. Thanks in advance.

HTML code for labels

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="radioo">Commission type <b style="color:red;">*</b></label>
         <div class="col-lg-10" required>
           <label class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-radio">
             <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="comission_type" value="0" checked="checked">
             <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
             <span class="custom-control-label">Fixed price</span>
           </label>
           <label class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-radio">
             <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="comission_type" value="1">
             <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
             <span class="custom-control-label">Percentage wise</span>
           </label>
           <label class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-radio">
             <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="comission_type" value="2">
             <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
             <span class="custom-control-label">Monthly</span>
           </label>
           <label class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-radio">
             <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="comission_type" value="3">
             <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
             <span class="custom-control-label">Yearly</span>
           </label>
     </div>
```

HTML code for div

```
<div id="fixPerDiv" style="display:block;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1">
          <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table" id = 'commision_tbl' >
          <tr>
              <td width = '20%'>Start price</td>
              <td width = '20%'>End price</td>
              <td width = '20%'>Start date</td>
              <td width = '20%'>End date</td>
              <td width = '20%'>Comission</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><input type="number" name="commissions_start_price[]" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Start Price" required="required" /></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="commissions_end_price[]" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="End Price" required="required"/></td>
            <td><div class="input-with-icon"><input type="text" data-provide="datepicker" value="" data-date-today-highlight="true" name="start_date[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Start date" required="required"/><span class="icon icon-calendar input-icon"></span></div></td>
            <td><div class="input-with-icon"><input type="text" data-provide="datepicker" value="" data-date-today-highlight="true" name="end_date[]" class="form-control" placeholder="End date" required="required"/><span class="icon icon-calendar input-icon"></span></div></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="commissions_amount[]" class="form-control"  value="" placeholder="Commision price" required="required"/></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
                <td colspan="6" align = "center">
                    <input type="button" value="Add More" id="price_addmorebtn" class="btn btn-outline-info">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Script code for disabling two fields for monthly/yearly radio buttons (Incomplete)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('called');
   $('input[type=radio][name=comission_type]').change(function() {
       if (this.value == '0' || this.value == '1') {


         $("#fixPerDiv").css("display","block");


       }
       else if (this.value == '2' || this.value == '3') {


           $("#fixPerDiv").css("display","block");

       }
   });
});
</script>
```

Script for add button

```
<script>
$('#price_addmorebtn').click(function(){
     var tr = "<tr>";
     tr += "<td><input type=\"number\" name=\"commissions_start_price[]\" class=\"form-control\"  placeholder=\"Start Price\"  required /></td>";
     tr += "<td><input type=\"number\" name=\"commissions_end_price[]\" class=\"form-control\"  placeholder=\"End Price\" required /></td>";
     tr += "<td><div class=\"input-with-icon\"><input name=\"start_date[]\" placeholder=\"Start date\" data-provide=\"datepicker\" data-date-today-highlight=\"true\" class=\"form-control\" required /><span class=\"icon icon-calendar input-icon\"></span></div></td>";
     tr += "<td><div class=\"input-with-icon\"><input name=\"end_date[]\" placeholder=\"Start date\" data-provide=\"datepicker\" data-date-today-highlight=\"true\" class=\"form-control\" required /><span class=\"icon icon-calendar input-icon\"></span></div></td>";
     tr += "<td><input type=\"number\" name=\"commissions_amount[]\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Commision price\" required /></td>";
     tr += "<td><span class = 'romoverow icon icon-close' style=\"cursor:pointer; padding-top:12px;\" title=\"Click to remove this row.\"></span></td>";
     $('#commision_tbl tr:last').before(tr);
 });
 $(document).on('click','.romoverow',function(){
     //alert('Hello');
      $(this).closest( 'tr').remove();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML code for div**

```
<div id="fixPerDiv" style="display:block;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1">
          <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table" id = 'commision_tbl' >
          <tr>
              <td width = '20%'>Start price</td>
              <td width = '20%'>End price</td>
              <td width = '20%'>Start date</td>
              <td width = '20%'>End date</td>
              <td width = '20%'>Comission</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><input type="number" name="commissions_start_price[]" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Start Price" required="required" /></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="commissions_end_price[]" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="End Price" required="required"/></td>
            <td><div class="input-with-icon"><input type="text" data-provide="datepicker" value="" data-date-today-highlight="true" name="start_date[]" class="form-control start_date" placeholder="Start date" required="required"/><span class="icon icon-calendar input-icon"></span></div></td>
            <td><div class="input-with-icon"><input type="text" data-provide="datepicker" value="" data-date-today-highlight="true" name="end_date[]" class="form-control end_date" placeholder="End date" required="required"/><span class="icon icon-calendar input-icon"></span></div></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="commissions_amount[]" class="form-control"  value="" placeholder="Commision price" required="required"/></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
                <td colspan="6" align = "center">
                    <input type="button" value="Add More" id="price_addmorebtn" class="btn btn-outline-info">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**Script for add button**

```
    $('#price_addmorebtn').click(function(){
    var selected_val = $("input[type=radio][name=comission_type]:checked").val();    
    var date_disabled="";
    if (selected_val == '2' || selected_val == '3') {
      date_disabled=" disabled ";
    }
     var tr = "<tr>";
     tr += "<td><input type=\"number\" name=\"commissions_start_price[]\" class=\"form-control\"  placeholder=\"Start Price\"  required /></td>";
     tr += "<td><input type=\"number\" name=\"commissions_end_price[]\" class=\"form-control\"  placeholder=\"End Price\" required /></td>";
     tr += "<td><div class=\"input-with-icon\"><input name=\"start_date[]\" placeholder=\"Start date\" data-provide=\"datepicker\" data-date-today-highlight=\"true\" class=\"form-control start_date\" required"+date_disabled+" /><span class=\"icon icon-calendar input-icon\"></span></div></td>";
     tr += "<td><div class=\"input-with-icon\"><input name=\"end_date[]\" placeholder=\"Start date\" data-provide=\"datepicker\" data-date-today-highlight=\"true\" class=\"form-control end_date\" required"+date_disabled+" /><span class=\"icon icon-calendar input-icon\"></span></div></td>";
     tr += "<td><input type=\"number\" name=\"commissions_amount[]\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Commision price\" required /></td>";
     tr += "<td><span class = 'romoverow icon icon-close' style=\"cursor:pointer; padding-top:12px;\" title=\"Click to remove this row.\"></span></td>";
     $('#commision_tbl tr:last').before(tr);
 });
     $(document).on('click','.romoverow',function(){
         //alert('Hello');
          $(this).closest( 'tr').remove();
     });
```

**Script code for disabling two fields for monthly/yearly radio buttons**

```
$('input[type=radio][name=comission_type]').change(function() {
       if (this.value == '0' || this.value == '1') {
         $(".start_date").attr("disabled",false);
         $(".end_date").attr("disabled",false);


       }
       else if (this.value == '2' || this.value == '3') {

          $(".start_date").attr("disabled",true);
          $(".end_date").attr("disabled",true);           

       }
   });
```

Comment: Amazing, Thank you so much. But there's one prob, when I click on monthly/yearly radio buttons, the row shows disabled two fields as required.But when clicked on add more button, the new rows doesn't disable the two fields but when change the radio button to yearly/percentage/fixed and vice versa, then only all the added rows changes to disabled two fields of monthly/yearly.Now what I require is when I click on add more button for monthly/yearly div I should get the disabled (two) fields. Than you so much :-) @B.desai